How to upload file to google-cloud-storage in Android?
My bucket is public, I tested by gsutil, file upload is success.
gsutil cp demo.mp4 gs://bucketname

In my Android project, google-cloud-storage version is 2.36.1
implementation "com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage:2.36.1"

Granted internet permission.
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

This is upload code.
Thread {
    val storage: Storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().service
    val file = Paths.get(getAbsolutePathFromUri(event.outputResults.outputUri))
    val bucketName = "backetname"
    val blobName = file.fileName.toString()
    val bucket = storage.get(bucketName)
    bucket.create(blobName, Files.readAllBytes(file))
}.start()

The app crash at val bucket = storage.get(bucketName)
Error is:

java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'java.util.stream.Collector com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.cloud.storage.UnifiedOpts$Opts' (declaration of 'com.google.cloud.storage.UnifiedOpts$Opts' appears in /data/app/~~k3FPbsvDs05Ol9WHS7nIQA==/com.android.example.camerax.video-Yn9EyF9sDYOAtVY7XEmMUw==/base.apk!classes8.dex)

Why gsutil is success but Android is fail? How to upload in Android?

Try downgrading the   google-cloud-storage  version to 2.23.0, as suggested in this thread1, also check this thread2

You're generally not supposed to use the GCP backend SDKs inside Android apps (mostly because it's a terrible idea to expose your private service account credentials to a public app).  Performing uploads to a cloud storage bucket is generally performed using Firebase SDKs and controlled using security rules.

@CL So Have you checked the above comments?
